# Add wireless TV like in windows

Tags: fedora

In windows you can do 'Add Wireless dock/device' and then simply cast to TV. Is there a way to do it in linux? I'm using Fedora.

Windows:
[image]

I would then be able to see my desktop on my TV.
https://windowsloop.com/how-to-connect-to-a-wireless-display-windows-10/

I've tried installing Gnome Network Display, it does find my TV but after trying to connect doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What TV are you using?  Does it support a particular kind of casting, like google chromecast?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Is any message printed?

Comment: I've added steps of adding TV in windows. Is there something similar that can be done in fedora? I didn't have to use chromecast. Simply add new device feature in windows and my laptop would duplicate displays wirelessly with my Samsung smart TV.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a [GNOME network display](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-network-displays) implementation of the Miracast protocol.  I don’t have a device to test against so I don’t know if it works.  I see it is packaged on my Fedora 33 system.

There is a [debugging section](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-network-displays/-/tree/master#debugging) that might guide you through any issues.  If it still doesn’t work, file an issue.  I see there are a couple with Tizen TVs (what Samsung runs).